# Write update mongo query with multiple where clause

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

New to mongo and I'm struggling to write update mongo query with multiple where clause

Lets say I have a employee list

```
name    |emp_id | old phone number | new phone number
Steve   |123    | 123-456-7896     | 801-123-4567
John    |456    | 123-654-9878     | 702-123-4567
Steve   |789    | 789-123-7890     | 504-123-4567
```

I would like to write a mongo query essentially saying

Update to new phone number where both name and emp_id matches. The document has about 200 entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're having multiple entires to be updated, you can have something like this :

When you say you've a list - Considering its in a file or somewhere to be processed through code then try to read data into an array :

```
let dataArray = [{name: Steve, emp_id: 123, new_phone_number :801-123-4567},{name: John, emp_id: 456, new_phone_number :702-123-4567},....]

db.getCollection('YourCollection').bulkWrite(
  dataArray.map((each) => 
    ({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { 'name': each.name, 'emp_id': each.emp_id  },
        update: { $set: { phone_number: each.new_phone_number } }
      }
    })
  )
)
```

So here we're considering `phone_number` as your field to be updated, We didn't consider maintaining two fields old_phone_number & new_phone_number in the documents.

Or in case if you wanted to have two phones numbers in the document then:

```
db.getCollection('YourCollection').bulkWrite(
      dataArray.map((each) => 
        ({
          updateOne: {
            filter: { 'name': each.name, 'emp_id': each.emp_id  },
            update: { $set: { new_phone_number: each.new_phone_number } }
          }
        })
      )
    )
```

As the above - we're injecting a new field `new_phone_number` to all matched documents, final outcome will have old phone number as a field `phone_number` and also new phone number in a field `new_phone_number` .

Also as you haven't mentioned anything particular, if you really need to update each record individually making multiple DB calls, then you can normally use `.update()` or `.updateOne()` or `.updateMany()` `.findAndModify()` depends on your requirement/interest.

[findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/index.html) , [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html) , [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html) , [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

By Default, MongoDB [$update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method updates single record. But if you want to update multiple documents matching criteria, then you can use Multi parameter (set this to true).

```
db.people.update(
   { name: "Steve", emp_id:123 },  //this is first parameter of update method. Define your query here
   {
      new_phone_number: 111-111-111  //This is second parameter. Update operation here
   },
   { multi: true }  // This is third one. Options here
)
```

Also look at [$updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) and [$updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)